# Передача параметров в запрос pgx Golang

Tags: postgresql, golang

Есть массив `params` который имеет тип `string` количество элементов массива меняется в зависимости от тела запроса, как передать массив параметров в запрос:

```
db.Query(ctx, query, ARRAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы отправить `[]string` в запрос надо преобразовать его в тип `[]interface{}`
Для этого мы должны наш ARRAY c типом []string:

```
params := make([]interface{}, len(ARRAY))
for i, v := range(ARRAY) {
    params[i] = v
}
```

и тогда уже как сказал @user419509 делать в запросе троеточие:

```
db.Query(ctx, query, ARRAY...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить троеточие должно сработать `db.Query(ctx, query, ARRAY...)`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sRixdkg не, подчеркивает собака

Comment: cорян забыл сказать что массив должен быть массивом интерфейсов как писал @khalinmaxim

Comment: да это я ответил на свой вопрос XD